# Sense Hat's API show_message function cannot be stopped in a middle of message

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I'm super new to Python language. I want to stop displaying the message on Sense Hat on Raspberry Pi "MSG before middle stick" when I release the stick, start to print the message "Hey" from the demo_display_string method.

```
import threading
import time
from sense_hat import SenseHat

busy = True
DISPLAY_STRING = "Hey"
run = False

def demo_display_string(arg_list):
    global DISPLAY_STRING
    global run
    run = True
    while run:
        sense.show_message(DISPLAY_STRING, text_colour=(255,0,0))
        for event in sense.stick.get_events():
            if event.action == 'released':
                print(event.action)
                if event.direction == 'middle':
                    run = False

def menu():
    global CURRENT_POSITION_IN_MENU
    busy = False
    exists = False
    while True:
        if not busy:
            # msg = positions[CURRENT_POSITION_IN_MENU][1]
            msg = "MSG before middle stick"
            sense.show_message(msg, scroll_speed=0.05)

        for event in sense.stick.get_events():
            sense.clear()
            if event.action == 'released':
                if event.direction == 'middle':
                    busy = True
                    demo_display_string(None)
                    busy = False

sense = SenseHat()

menu()
```

It seems to work, but the problem is that sense.show_message is blocking and won't stop until the end of the message. So when I press the stick in a middle of "MSG before middle stick" it still displays the whole message and after that start displaying "Hey". I want it to happen in real time when I press stick, message changes.

Answer (score 0):

The show_message function has no option to interupt the scrolling text. So python shows the whole text and then continues with the event loop. You have to write a threaded version of show_message, that checks for a break event in regular intervals and fire this event from another thread in case of a joystick input.